# How to Create a Java Project for Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have just transitioned into Visual Studio Code from Eclipse for Java. I want to create a simple HelloWorld folder which has src and bin folders. However, I do not know how to create the .classpath, .project, and .settings the same way Eclipse does it. How do I do this?

Comment: Visual Studio Code does not (and will not) use eclipse .classpath, project and .settings files. Why would you assume that it does?

Comment: Hello it says:

Maven, Eclipse and Gradle Java project are supported through Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat, by utilizing M2Eclipse which provides Maven support and Buildship which provides Gradle support through the Eclipse JDT Language Server.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/java

Regardless, how would I create a brand new Java Project with src and bin in Eclipse. I want to practice all the problems in LeetCode.

Comment: And [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java) RedHat says "Recognizes projects with maven or gradle build files in the directory hierarchy." - the [m2eclipse project](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) **provides** maven support to eclipse; it's a plugin. It provides maven support to VS Code. Since you don't want to use maven, I can only suggest you want something else.

Comment: Alright, lol. I just wanted a simple way to write code haha. How would I even go about Maven or Gradle then? 

I just want to build, run, debug code. Is this possible?

Comment: Super simple way to write code: Download Netbeans and use it.

Comment: I know how to do that. I just wanted to make it work in VCS cuz its cross-platform and I am sick of having multiple IDE's for each language. I already got it setup for Python, Go, C/C++. Java works but I want to do the build, run, debug lol.

Comment: Java works just fine for quick programs in Code. I do it, and use it often. But that's simple stuff that I use the integrated terminal with. Any type of efforts beyond that would be with an IDE. IMHO, go JetBrains for the closest thing to it but with all the candy.

Comment: **By the closest thing to it, I meant an IDE that supports many languages well.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs guys !!!

Answer (score 9):

Hit Ctrl+Shift+P to show all commands, then type "Java" and select "Java: Create Java Project"

Comment: For some reason I don't have this command in my VS Code. Can you help with troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code doesn´t have this orientation of creating a project because it´s file oriented. It´s on of the diferences with Visual Studio.

It means that creating a project structure is based on folders and files, and no file references and links the folders and files to a project.
If you want to create a project with src and bin folders, you´ve to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

First you need install some packages for Visual Studio Code.
You can find all in this Microsoft Support page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial

After you have installing it, you can press `CTRL+SHIFT+P` and type `Java` for get all commands.

In your case, for make a new project, follow these tips:

1. Press keys: `CTRL+SHIFT+P` to open Command menu
2. Type: `Java: Create Java Project`
3. Select a project type, like `No build tools`
4. Select the project location
5. Type the project name, like: `My first program`
6. If appear the alert window, trust the authors of the files in this folder by pressing the button `Yes, I trust the authors`

Now your project is created. You can see the folder `src` with the file `App.java` and the Hello World's code inside.

Now for testing your first program, press the right mouse button on `App.java` file and select `Run Java`

[image: menu from visual studio code]

Now, if all works, your Hello World's program is printed on your Terminal window.
[image: output in terminal window]